# Same redirect works for one www to non-www domain, but create redirect loop for the second using nginx

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, nginx

I have 2 Meteor apps using Nginx to redirect to different ports. For each app I have configuration files that are the same, but different ports and domains. First one redirects from www to non-www without any problem, but second one shows message :

> This webpage has a redirect loop

In my-domain1.conf:

```js
server {
    server_name www.saveting.com;
    return 301 $scheme://saveting.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen                80;

  server_name           saveting.com www.saveting.com;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/app.dev.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/app.dev.error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

in the my-domain2.conf:

```js
server {
    server_name www.downloadinstagramvideo.com;
    return 301 $scheme://downloadinstagramvideo.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen            80;

  server_name       downloadinstragramvideo.com www.downloadinstagramvideo.com;

  access_log          /var/log/nginx/app.dev.access.log;
  error_log           /var/log/nginx/app.dev.error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

I tried to make one redirect for all domains using [this tutorial](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx/www-non-www-redirection/), using following code:

```js
server {
        server_name "~^(?!www\.).*" ;
        return 301 $scheme://www.$host$request_uri;
}
```

but that didn't work for any at all. What can cause redirect loop in the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `server_name` in the second/forth block includes the name of the first/third block, which is wrong. Each server block should have non-overlapping names. Such as:

```
server {
  server_name www.saveting.com;
  ...
}
server {
  server_name saveting.com;
  ...
}
server {
  server_name www.downloadinstagramvideo.com;
  ...
}
server {
  server_name downloadinstragramvideo.com;
  ...
}
```